# Joined SELECT blocking UPDATE inside WHILE loop

Tags: c#, sql, timeout, locking, block

Gets all fields from `Table` but only the ones created last, for each different `Field`

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Table AS t1 
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT Field
           , MAX(CreatedOn) AS MaxDate 
      FROM Table 
      WHERE ImportedOn IS NULL 
      AND Status <> 'error' 
      GROUP BY Field) AS t2 
ON t1.Field = t2.Field 
AND t1.CreatedOn = t2.MaxDate
```

I read this data inside a while loop. At the end I try to update the same table - the same record read - and it gives me a timeout. I figure its because the table is blocked for changes.

My question is: **How to work around it? Any way to 'fix' the query so it'll accept updates?**

*Extra info: If I query without JOIN it works perfectly.*

Comment: What database engine are working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing an `UPDATE` row by row after every read; do a `JOIN` with the table and update. Something like below [A sample; not the exact query]

```
UPDATE t1
SET column_name = tab.some_column_name
FROM Table t1
JOIN
(
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Table AS t1 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Field, 
MAX(CreatedOn) AS MaxDate 
FROM Table 
WHERE ImportedOn IS NULL 
AND Status <> 'error' 
GROUP BY Field
) AS t2 
ON t1.Field = t2.Field 
AND t1.CreatedOn = t2.MaxDate
) tab 
ON t1.Field = tab.Field
```

Comment: thing is I need some data from the `SELECT` for other operations in other tables.

Comment: Then consider pulling your query result in a temporary table or tabletype variable. then you can use it in multiple places. Also, consider accepting the answer if its helpful.

Comment: Id thought of doing something like that but I changed the code a little bit. Ima mark it as answer though it wasnt what I used just to close this.